# Why is Django looking for templates in the wrong directory

Tags: python, django

Why is Django looking for Template in the wrong directory?

django is looking here: sempire\double_ch_control_app\templates\double_channel_control.html

instead of conventionally here: sempire\double_ch_control_app\templates\double_ch_control_app\double_channel_control.html

I have more than one app on the django project but this very app keep looking up templates on the wrong directory

Comment: It depends on the template path you trying to render in your view. share your code

Comment: check the settings.py file in the project folder, make sure the path is correct: 
DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files
APP_DIRS tells whether the engine should look for templates inside installed applications TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]

Comment: Thanks so much i got it, the problem is actually coming from the template path am trying to render